# How do I simultaneously distribute a GPIO 3.3V logic signal to a batch of identical devices with 1.8V input

Tags: impedance, switching, gpio

I'm asking how to distribute a 3.3V GPIO output logic signal onto many IDENTICAL devices that have 1.8V input.  The first device is no more than 4m from the MCU.  Each device is tapped (wired in parallel) to the control line at a distance of no more than 15cm.  Each device is spaced 1m apart on the control line.

MCU - - - 4m - - - Dev1 - 1m - Dev 2 - 1m - Dev 3 - 1m - Dev 4...

I can successfully generate the signal from our 125MHz GPIO already, but I can't use the GPIO to distribute the signal to all of these devices DIRECTLY because: adding more than 3 devices to the GPIO line (in parallel) buries the GPIO voltage (it can't maintain 1.65V HIGH), and because adding more than 7 devices to GPIO line (in parallel) draws more than the 12mA that the GPIO can accommodate.  I need 20 or more devices.

I don't know how to determine the impedance of each of these devices and the vendor won't release the specs.  If there's a confident way to do that, I'd appreciate a link or a walk-through of the process.

It was suggested below that each device is likely to have a 1k pulldown.  The schematic is available.  I can see a 22k resistor on the backside of the input pin, but the rest is above my skill level.

The required signal profile is a loop:
between 1.000 and 19.000s HIGH @ 1.65V + 40ns LOW.
I'm triggering the devices to capture every 19 seconds (or less) in order to keep them awake (I dispose of the unwanted captures).

I'm guessing there's a device that can go between my GPIO output and my control line (input) that will insulate my GPIO from the load, but still maintain signal integrity.  Here's an example of a level shifter... but I'm not partial to the device.  Whatever works best is good for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150087/discussion-on-question-by-torpedo51-how-do-i-simultaneously-distribute-a-gpio-3); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I switch them all off then on rapidly without exceeding the max current draw of my power source?

You can't if you want them all on together.

There may be solutions to your real problem if you explain in your original question (not here in the comments) what your overall goal is and how you are regulating a GPIO pin from 3.3 V (capital 'V' for volt) to 1.65 V and what is determining the 40 mA max (the GPIO rating or an external current limiter).

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I'm not necessarily asking how to get the GPIO to switch them on and off directly, because I already know it can't due to voltage drop and exceeding max pin current.  I'm asking if the load can be switched indirectly by the GPIO, i.e. a "relay" such as a level shifter, transistor, etc?  Thx

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. The first part of the question is how to switch a load which exceeds draw from power source.

Obviously, there's no way to power a load that requires more than your supply can provide.

But then again, a GPIO pin is not a power supply to begin with.

I don't know where you got the information that a Raspberry Pi Pico (which is a board for RP2040) GPIO pin can provide 50mA current, but I am pretty sure it can't. Feel free to prove me wrong with a credible source, but 50mA GPIO on a generic microcontroller is just something you would not expect to see, and it would be extemely surprising if true.

The RP2040 datasheet says a pin can output at least voltage of 2.62V at 12mA, which is the strongest drive strength setting.

According to graphs in the datasheet, typically when drawing 30mA the voltage has already dropped to 2.5V. The graph does not go beyond that, and the datasheet is anyway quite terrible, as it does not contain safe nominal or even absolute maximum limits like you would expect from a professional data sheet. So as it does not read anywhere, 50mA could be the current when you short circuit the pin to 0V, or 50mA could be the absolute maximum rating for permanent damage.

If I had to use this chip and guess the safe limit you should not exceed under normal conditions, it would be the specified rating of 12mA. If I had to guess a safe limit to prevent damage, it might be around 20 to 30mA.

If we do continue with the assumption that you can draw 50mA without damaging the GPIO pin, and you can toggle it fast enough to give out sharp 1ns switching pulses and control something, it might be fine.

But if the thing you are controlling with GPIO is a power input to a 1.65V regulator, that's a problem.

Even if the GPIO can send 1ns pulses out, the regulator sure can't.

The regulator requires a 10uF output capacitor to be stable or it won't work. The regulator output needs to be guaranteed to be at least 10mA or it won't work. Even if you tried to charge the 10uF output capacitor from 0V to 1.65V at 1A current, it would still take 16.5 microseconds to charge. To extrapolate, you need 16.5A to charge it in 1us, and 16500A to charge it in 1ns. Even if that were possible, you can't discharge the output capacitor with the GPIO, so it must be left to decay by itself through the load. And the load being a resistance of 1019 ohms, the RC time constant is 10 milliseconds.

So there is no way you can use a regulator on a GPIO pin for fast switching and level conversion. GPIO pins and regulators are not meant for that purpose.

Comment: I suspect OP got mixed up... 50mA is the ["_Maximum Total IOVDD current_"](https://imgur.com/a/IcTc0z9)

Comment: @Justme,  excellent thx. The GPIO signal is fast enough (proven) but there is an unusable voltage drop when the GPIO is wired directly to voltage dividers, transistors or MOSFETs on the line or in front of each load (I can't hold the control line HIGH 1.65V even with just a few loads).  I envision a "relay" solution that would  isolate the switching circuit current from the switched circuit.  However, the forum wasn't embracing a question that included a proposal, and that's why I'm asking here generically, "how do I switch the load (indirectly?) from my GPIO?"  Level shifter? See new diagram.

Comment: @torpedo51 That wasn't apparent from the question, as you referenced the GPIO pin as power supply. Your question may have been edited when I last saw it. But you say your load is resistors. I bet from your previous questions that your load is actually twenty pieces of 1.65V logic inputs with 1k pull-down on each. But you did not say that. Most likely your loads are also distributed over some length or are, so the question should really be how to distribute a 3.3V logic level signal with these timing parameters to 20 logic level inputs with another logic level and over some length of wiring.

Comment: @Justme Yes, revised thoroughly... thx!

Comment: @torpedo51 I did not mean to edit this question, just commented on that what you asked does not seem to reflect your problem and how to solve it. You already asked a question, got answers to that, and then you changed the question about powering a few ten mA load to distributing a high speed data pulse over several meters to several receivers  - a wildly different question! Now these answers for your original question are invalid.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the feedback and your patience.  I've asked this question several times in several formats because everyone prefers a different one.  From my perspective, I haven't changed anything, I've continued to make the question more accurate.  I'm sorry either way.  I just don't understand the sorcery involved with EE that will help move me forward.  I'm not the first person to drive a load with a GPIO that it can't handle;  people keep telling me to use a "buffer"... but not how to compute/select one.  Thx!

Comment: @torpedo51 Yes but the largest problem is getting the high speed 40ns pulse to all 20 devices on a 25 meter bus. How to convert 3.3V to such bus transmitter or from bus to 1.8V logic level are separate and trivial issues. What are the specs for your 40ns pulse, at what timing or precision it must be received by the modules? Please note that light travels 1 meter in 3.33 nanoseconds, so on a 20 meter bus an electrical signal travels 100ns. The pulse is much shorter than the time it takes to travel 20 meters. So you must be able to define how you want the system to work before implementing it.

Comment: @Justme Aha!  Thx!  The short answer is: "not critical".  20 or more cameras triggered to capture "at about the same time".  Precise synchronization isn't required, Assuming that a perceptible frame rate for motion is roughly 30Hz, then the signal has ample opportunity to travel a long distance without a noticeable affect (I'm not capturing a subject in motion anyway).  The 40ns LOW is required to trigger a capture (on devices that I'm not using, the duration of the LOW pulse also determines the exposure duration).

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your circuit. The pico should be supplying the logic signal, but not the power. Use a transistor, or perhaps a buffer chip. And draw power from a separate source.

If you need 1.65V, use a voltage regulator and create a power rail. Then switch power from this rail to your load.

As justme said, if you try to use a voltage regulator as a level shifter it's going to be extremely slow and unstable, as it's not designed to be used that way.

Comment: Yes! I've thoroughly revised the question and pencil sketch to reflect this. I don't know what type of buffer will work. Is there a check down to help me understand what is better: transistor, MOSFET, level shifter, or some other buffer? I don't know what specific questions to ask or details to provide to narrow the selection down to something that will work with confidence. Thx!

Comment: I think you should ask a new question honestly. This Q&A is hopelessly confusing due to your changes to the question. Don't feel bad tough, knowing what question to ask is part of the challenge.

Comment: I would look for a buffer IC that meets your criteria. The reason being that it will be well characterized in the datasheet, and will have high input impedance. You should be aware that such a fast pulse over long wires will likely require impedance matching. A high side switch formed from a pfet and nfet would likely work, but you would have to design it carefully to achieve such a short pulse cleanly

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't transmit a 40ns pulse along a pair of wires without reflections obliterating the nice square edges, unless you properly terminate the transmission line at both ends.

Also, if you inject a 1.8V signal at the transmitter end of the line, that termination and the impedance of the line itself will attenuate signal amplitude, meaning that you'll not get 1.8V at the receivers.

Over 4m, the wire pair itself will have significant capacitance, which when combined with the output impedance of the transmitter, forms a low pass filter which will flatten those fast edges.

I suggest that you transmit your signal at the full 3.3V, and employ signal recovery and level translation individually at each receiver. This solves a few issues:

- The line can be properly terminated, to eliminate reflections
- Line termination may mandate significant signal loop current, but this helps noise immunity. Induced currents in the long signal loop, from nearby sources, have to be much greater to compete with a deliberately strong signal current.
- You don't have to concern yourself with attenuation, you let each receiver deal with that.
- No need for a separate 1.8V supply
- The GPIO output can be buffered trivially, alleviating any load on it.
- Signal recovery and conditioning at each receiver can place very little load on the transmission line, and locally deal with the receiver device's input impedance.

Instead of hunting for a line driver, a "cheat" that's worked for me before is to use two or more gates in a 74HC-series logic IC, such as the 7408 (4 AND gates) to produce a very low impedance signal, and terminate the line as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foBeki.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The combined output impedance of all the gates and their output resistors is about 100Ω and the transmission line is terminated at the far end by a matching 100Ω, formed by R5 and R6. These values are OK for a standard twisted pair (ethernet CAT5 style), but you'll need to tweak all the resistor values for other types of cable such as coax.

Signal current will be \$\frac{3.3V}{200\Omega}= 17mA\$, which those gates' outputs can easily supply between them, crucially, in either high or low output state. TTL gates would not be suitable for this application due to their output asymmetry, so stick with CMOS.

As a potential divider, R5 and R6 centre the signal at about 1V. The whole termination network attenuates the signal by 50% (100Ω at each end, with the signal being at the junction between them), so we can expect the signal arriving at the receivers to be at best 1.0±0.8V, either 0.2V or 1.8V. The longer the cables, the greater the attenuation, so amplitude could be significantly less.

That signal may well be good enough for your devices already, but since their input characteristics are ambiguous, you should probably buffer it. Whatever you use, it has to react quickly to those those fast edges. One solution could be a fast comparator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frJhuD.png)</sup>

R9 and R10 provide a reference potential of about 1V. I chose this potential to prevent the comparator's inputs from ever leaving their acceptable range, 0V to 2.1V (according to the [MAX976 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/cn/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1795.pdf)).  R11 and R12 implement 200mV or so of hysteresis, for noise immunity, with switching thresholds near  1.1V and 0.9V.

R7 and R8 scale the 0V/3.3V down to 0V and 1.8V.

Oh, and don't forget power supply decoupling capacitors - one on *every* IC.

Just a quick disclaimer, I haven't tested any of this, it's all only a few of my thoughts on your problem. Unless I've missed something, this *should* enable you to transmit 40ns pulses over a 4m wire pair, but I can't guarantee anything.